# Tomcat (probably) closes before ROOT directory is entirely populated

Tags: debian, tomcat

on a Ubuntu 12.04 machine, Tomcat 7.0.22 ,

I have a bash script that copies a ROOT.war file to a specific library, at which point Tomcat deploys it to a directory called ROOT. A few lines later, the bash script restarts (closes, then runs again) Tomcat.

Problem is -

in many instances (I've yet to pinpoint which, but suspect slower machines) the ROOT directory isn't entirely populated. I suspect that Tomcat closes before it finishes the deployment of the ROOT.war. When I put in 'sleep 10' after the copy and before the restart, the problem is much less common. I could put in 'sleep 20', but I'd really prefer to know when and if I need this otherwise unwelcome delay.

Question is -

how can I get feedback from Tomcat regarding the completion of the deployment? Or otherwise shutdown Tomcat in a way that lets it finish the deployment before shutting down? - In cli, preferably available to bash scripting, as the whole thing's ought to be automated.

Comment: \what is your tomcat version?

Comment: right - Tomcat 7.0.22, edited the question to show this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for Tomcat, you could have several alternatives:

- After tomcat v7, several versions can coexist. Launch them as ROOT##001.war and so on. [Zero-downtime Deployment (and Rollback) in Tomcat; a walkthrough and a checklist](http://java-monitor.com/forum/showthread.php?t=1288)
- ROOT.war is in reality a zip file. If somewhat it is critical for you the deployment time, unzip it yourself in a link in the same tree, when unziping is finished move the production link to name_old, change your directory to name, and then restart to minimize downtime.
- Depending on your local configuration, you also may see a distinct line when finishing deployment in catalina.out. Your mileage may vary, cannot recommend a particular message.
- With automatic deployment, and depending on the configuration, you might not even need to restart tomcat, but just placing there a new WAR and deleting the previous version. [Automatic Deployment - Use cases](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/automatic-deployment.html)

I also advise to read the [Deployer How To](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/deployer-howto.html).

Due to security concerns, I also urge you to update your tomcat installation. [Apache » Tomcat » 7.0.22 : Security Vulnerabilities](http://www.cvedetails.com/vulnerability-list/vendor_id-45/product_id-887/version_id-118822/Apache-Tomcat-7.0.22.html) *if your tomcat is no being managed by the automated security updates*

Comment: Thanks, I'll probably end up using the zip option. Didn't see anything interesting in the catalina.out after the 'Deployinh ... ROOT.war' line.